# How to remove marker edges in seaborn.pairplot()?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn has a handy function pairplot to create a matrix of scatter plots. Unfortunately, some standard matplotlib commands don't work with it.

```
sns.pairplot(matrix[cols[:4]].head(100), plot_kws=dict(alpha=.5, mew=0))
```

The markers get some ugly white edges. I tried `mew` for `markeredgewidth` keyword to remove them as it would be used in matplotlib, but that is an unknown property for seaborn. How can I remove these edges?

Answer (score 6):

A `scatter` does not have a `mew` keyword. It is `edgecolor` instead. Hence

```
sns.pairplot(data, plot_kws=dict(edgecolor="none"))
```

would remove the white edge around the scatterpoints.

Comment: If one wants to make a thick/thin edged marker, is there currently an alternative to matplotlib's `mew` in seaborn? If not, is there a way to request this feature for the sake of convenience?

Comment: @Bazingaa All arguments to `plot_kws` should simply be passed on to scatter. Try e.g. `plot_kws=dict(edgecolor="gold", linewidth=5, s=100)`.

Comment: That simply means that `edgecolor="none"` does the same thing as `plot_kws=dict(linewidth=0)`. I get the same result. Do you agree?

Comment: Correct. Neither a line with no width, nor a line with no color are drawn.

Answer (score 3):

[ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)'s answer is much more precise. Alternatively, you can also use a workaround: Set the color of choice for both the face and the edges of the markers as (example from the docs)

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris, plot_kws=dict(facecolor='b', edgecolor="b"))
```

**EDIT** based on comments below IOBE's answer: Just specifying the `linewidth=0` also works the same way on markers as specifying `edgecolor="none"`.

```
g = sns.pairplot(iris, plot_kws=dict(linewidth=0))
```

[image]